# MSI installation and UAC

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer

We have our product installation built using WiX.
It needs to be executed on servers and, because of its nature, needs to create user and assign this user specific rights (e.g. Execute as Service)
For that we're using our own custom actions that are defined in C#-based custom actions library.

When we start installation by user who has administrative permissions, but is not administrator on Windows 2008 the system doesn't ask us to confirm that we want this application to be executed (UAC dialog is not shown).
As result, all these action fails because the MSI seems to be run without Administrative permissions.
We cannot make our action deferred because some of them need to be executed during UI sequence and need to be marked as "immediate".

How would we mark installer as one that needs Administrative permissions?
We tried WiX  attribute InstallPrivileges='elevated', but documentation says it is set by default and it didn't make any difference.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot mark the MSI directly to request Administrator privileges. However, you can try using an EXE bootstrapper which requests elevation through its manifest: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx

A better approach is to split your custom actions instead of a single action which does everything:

- use Immediate custom action which collect data from UI
- use Deferred with no impersonation custom action which use that data

The information collected by the UI custom actions can be stored in installer properties. These properties can be passed through Action Data (CustomActionData property) to the deferred actions.

Comment: Yes, I know that. Thanks for reminding. I thought there will be a way without doing that.

Comment: With bootstrapper, how to be with Uninstall/Repair functions - they also need to either remove the user or recreate the user in the case it was removed manually? And we understand that the Repair/Uninstall will be launched directly, without bootstrapper, which will make the same issue. Won't it?

Comment: If you want to maintain the user and its permissions, the installation would also need Admin privileges during maintenance. It's pretty hard to use a bootstrapper during maintenance. Advanced Installer has this feature if you really want it. I edited my post with another suggestion.

Comment: Thanks, this is probably an approach that we're going to choose - mark actions as non-impersonated. This will definitely limit some of the capabilities. E.g., we were verifying whether the user exists, whether the user can be created etc. during UI sequence. But it seems we will need to move all this to the deferred section.

Answer (score 1):

I use InstallPrivileges='elevated' in my install and it displays the UAC dialog on Windows 2008. Do you see the shield icon on the "Install" button?

Comment: No, I don't. I also use InstallPrivileges='elevated' and it doesn't display a shield icon. Not sure why.

Comment: I have just double checked my install on Windows 2008 and  InstallPrivileges="elevated" works. If you run with logging you should see this in the log: 
"Machine policy value 'AlwaysInstallElevated' is 0"
"User policy value 'AlwaysInstallElevated' is 0"

Then this later:
"MSI_LUA: Elevated credential consent provided. Install will run elevated"

I also noticed this: "Product installation will be elevated because user provided elevated credentials and product is being installed per-machine."

Is you install "per machine".

Comment: Yes, our install is per-machine and we don't get the Elevated window.

Comment: Did you see the messages described above in the log?

Comment: Something different... The log says "MSI_LUA: Setting AdminUser property to 1 because this is the client or the user has already permitted elevation". But I was not asked to permit elevation

Comment: This sounds to me like your user is already elevated (or at least Windows Installer thinks so). I have seen this in a VM when I logon with the default admin user. When you use system functions do they show the sheild or prompt to be elevated?

Comment: Yes, the system functions have the Shield and they show the Elevation Prompt when I try to launch them. When I'm logging in with a local admin no elevation prompts are shown and here we're testing the install under user who is a member of Administrators group, but is not an Administrator (default admin). Earlier in the log there's another string: "Running product {...} with user privileges. DisableMsiPolicy is set to or defaulted to 1. This is the client and the user does not have full admin token. Evaulation is delayed until after credentials provided. This install could still be blocked"

Comment: I'm not sure but this sounds like a local or group policy on the machine. I am interested in this as we have just started supporting Win2k8 so I'll try some different combinations of user and report back if I discover anything.